# In Python/NumPy, how to pad an array by replicating the elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example, if I have an array

```
[1, 2, 1]
```

and I want to get a new array which is 4 times the length

```
[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what [`numpy.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is for.

```
>>> x = numpy.array([1, 2, 1])
>>> numpy.repeat(x, 4)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do?:

```
def extend(lst, i): 
    return [e for e in lst for r in range(i)]
>>> extend([1,2,1], 4)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> extend([1,2,1], 3)
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: This isn't using numpy.

Comment: @Bas ? ... the example is with an array.